# Using a batch file to process a bunch of files in a folder

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, awk, sed, cmd

I'm trying to get this batch file to work.  I have about 200 files in a folder (C:\Users\bloughj\Documents\Fluxes)

I want the batch file to go through each file in that folder and extract a section of data using sed and awk (the binaries reside in a network folder K:\Physics\bin\1112\Tools).  Then write that section of data to an individual file named after the original input file and place that file in C:\Users\bloughj\Documents\Fluxes\output

My batch file is:

```
set bindirectory=K:\Physics\bin\1112\Tools
set outputdirectory=C:\Users\bloughj\Documents\Fluxes\output

for %%f in (C:\Users\bloughj\Documents\Fluxes\) do (

   call %bindirectory%\sed.exe -n '/---new---/,/---old---/ { p; }' %%f | 
   call %bindirectory%\gawk.exe '{ print $3 }' >> %outputdirectory%\%%f.txt
)
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  I keep getting an error 'The syntax of the command is incorrect.'.  Am I doing my for loop wrong?

Comment: I do not have sed or gawk, but I think the issue may have stemmed from the pipe... I'm not sure, but try testing it normally in cmd. I see in your code, you don't have `@echo off` so you should be able to see where the error is. If you do have `@echo off` try keeping it on.

Comment: you could combine the 2 into 1 `awk` program, something like `awk '/---new---/,/---old---/{print $3}'  %%f > %%f.out`. Good luck.

Comment: `Call` is for calling batch files in unusual ways. If you are piping then put second command on the same line.

Comment: I removed the call to sed and just used gawk:

`code`@echo on

set bindirectory=K:\Physics\bin\1112\Tools\
set outputdirectory=C:\Users\bloughj\Documents\Fluxes\output\

for %%f in (*) do (

 %bindirectory%gawk '/---new---/,/---old---/{print $3}' %%f > %outputdirectory%%%f.txt
)

It seems to work now.  Thanks.